# Where to recalculate static itemSize in UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

**Requirements**:

- layout logic placed in subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.
- same `itemSize` for every cell.
- `itemSize` only changes on size change of collection view, e.g. rotation.

Since `itemSize` is fixed, I have no need to implement any of the dynamic size methods. I just need to calculate and set `itemSize` at appropriate times.

**Question**: When and where do I update `itemSize`?

**Thoughts**: Ideally, I'd do it in response to `invalidateLayout` but there does not seem to be a place to hook into. `invalidateLayout` calls the dynamic sizing methods which I don't need. The only thing that is called is `prepare` which I'm currently using (abusing?) for that purpose. I'd also like to avoid having the view controller explicitly tell the layout to update, apart from invalidating.

Comment: Are you already overriding `UICollectionViewLayout`'s `func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool` and returning true? By default this will return false.

Comment: @KyleH Would I update the item size in there then?

Comment: No, returning true from this method will just ensure the custom layout goes through its layout calculations again when the bounds change. You can have functionality to determine what the current orientation is and return different item sizes from the `itemSize`'s getter.

Comment: I see, makes sense. So, I wouln't actually set the `itemSize`, I'd just return the value from the getter? Hadn't even thought about that.